# VBA moving entire set of data into different rows and columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am a total newbie using Ms VBA and i need your help
I have a dataset which i've formated into a sheet which basically goes from column A~BG and rows from 1~2100ish.

What i'm trying to do is move the whole data set to start from Column E and row at 13 since this is the format that the emulator will take it in.

What will be best way to do this?

Comment: Where is your code you have written thus far? Also, do you want it `cut` or `copied` Is the new destination a new sheet in same workbook?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1/ Insert rows and columns

```
Columns("A:D").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Rows("1:12").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

2/ Move the block

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("E13")
```

Answer (score 0):

That can help you a bit:

```
Range("A1:G2100").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("E13").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

E13 is starting of target position

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below.

```
Range("A1:G2100").Cut Sheet2.Range("k1")
```

Regards
Sasi